# RDS - automated snapshots with Backups disabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, backups

In order to take our own full and differential backups to S3 buckets (for restore to new instances), we would like to disable automated RDS backups (the automated backups bugger up the LSN's for our differentials).

But we don't really want to disable automated snapshot backups.

Is there some way to keep automated snapshots enabled (or scheduled) with Backups disabled?

Comment: What is your database? SQL Server?

Comment: yes, in my case it's SQL server,

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the AWS service called **AWS Backups.** This will serve your purpose by simply adding some tags and creating a backup plan.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html